# Is there a timetable of the Yom Kippur Avodah available?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, kohen-priest, yom-kippur

I'm trying to get a sense of how long each part of the Kohen Gadol's day was. I have the impression that the (outer) Musaf offering took much longer than the Torah reading, but I have no idea how much longer. And I don't know how long the "break" of waiting for the scapegoat to reach the Midbar was.

I know there are different opinions on the order of the rituals, but a timetable according to any recognized opinion would be great.

Comment: The distance to the cliff was 3 mil so it would have taken about an hour to get there (Yoma 6:8)

Comment: Perhaps a Cohen who is a *Gadol* or a *shochet* (but not a Cohen Gadol) among our readers can tell us how long it takes to slaughter a bull, separate the parts, get out the blood and burn it, takes? I'd venture that some *shochet* has made a BBQ using his own meat?

Comment: I don't think there is any rule about how long it is supposed to take, so it probably depended on the individual kohen gadol.